# Hangman game help, changing "?????" one letter at a time in order to show partially guessed words

Tags: python

I'm making a hangman game as a beginner project in python. I'm running into a snag with one part and it's driving me nuts.  I want to display the word as ???? and when the user guesses the right letter it will replace "?" with the correct letter in the correct spot.

Example:

The Secret word is ????

"User inputs f"

You are correct

Here is what you have so far f???

Here is the entire game's code so far

```
import random

print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following catagories')

Animal=['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard']
Clothing=['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf']
Weather=['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Stormy']
Colors=['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']

Alphabet= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')

catagory=int(input())

while catagory > 4:
    print('Your input isn\'t one of the catagories. Make sure your choice is a number from 1 to 4.')
    print('Try entering again')
    print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')
    catagory=int(input())

while catagory == 0: 
    print('Your input isn\'t one of the catagories. Make sure your choice _ 
is a number from 1 to 4.')
    print('Try entering again')
    print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')
    print('')
    print('You have ' + str(numberofguesses) + ' left.  Good luck.'
    catagory=int(input())

if catagory == 1: secretword=random.choice(Animal)
if catagory == 2: secretword=random.choice(Clothing)
if catagory == 3: secretword=random.choice(Weather)
if catagory == 4: secretword=random.choice(Colors)

hiddenword = ('?'*len(secretword))

print('')
print('The word you\'re after is ' + hiddenword)
print('')
print('Type one of the following letters, it must be lowercase.')
print(Alphabet)

i = input()

while numberofguesses != 0:

    if i in secretword:
        Alphabet.remove(i)
        print('')
        print('You guessed correctly')
        list(hiddenword)
        hiddenword=[i if x==str("?") else x for x in hiddenword]
        hiddenguessed= ''.join(hiddenword)
        print('Here is what you have so far '+ str(hiddenguessed))
        print('')
        print('Avalable letters left')
        print(Alphabet)      
        print('Guess another letter')
        i=input()

    else:
        numberofguesses = numberofguesses - 1
        Alphabet.remove(i)
        print('')
        print("You guessed wrong")
        print("")
        list(hiddenword)
        hiddenword=[i if x==str("?") else x for x in hiddenword]
        hiddenguessed= ''.join(hiddenword)
        print('Here is what you have so far '+ str(hiddenguessed))
        print('')
        print('You now have '+str(numberofguesses)+' guesses left.')
        print('Here is what you have so far '+ str(hiddenguessed))
        print('')
        print('Type one of the following letters, it must be lowercase.')
        print(Alphabet)
        i=input()
else:
    Print('Congrats you have won the game.  ' + _ 
str(hiddenguessed) + ' was the secret word')
```

I tried to make a list out of the strings and flip flop the characters around, but i'm not having any luck.

```
list(hiddenword)
hiddenword=[i if x==str("?") else x for x in hiddenword]
hiddenguessed= ''.join(hiddenword)
print('Here is what you have so far '+ str(hiddenguessed))
```

This is the best I could do, but all it does is replace all the "?" with the Guessed letter. Although it only does that if it is the correctly guessed letter Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `i` doing (or representing) in `hiddenword=[i if x==str("?") else x for x in hiddenword]`?

Comment: @AGNGazer `i` is the `input()` the user gives in the form of a string.

Comment: @AGNGazer `Secretword` = the actual word that is chosen from the catagories.  `Hiddenword` = a string made of "?" the same length as `Secretword`.  i = `input()` of the user.

Comment: So many errors in your code. Many variables are not defined before the first use. Then what is the purpose of underscores in many string concatenation operations such as `print('Here is what you have so far '+ _ str(hiddenwordplusguessedletters))`

Comment: `hiddenwordplusguessedletters` is never defined.

Comment: @AGNGazer the `_` is so I can show the same line of code on the next line.  What do you mean about the variables? A lot of them can't be defined until others have had things done to them first.  There probably are a lot of problems with it.  it's still a work in process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on a functioning version

```
import random
import string

print('Welcome to hangman')
print('Type one of the following catagories')

categorytypes = {
  "Animal": ['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard'],
  "Clothing": ['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf'],
  "Weather": ['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Stormy'],
  "Colors": ['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']
}

alphabet= list(string.ascii_lowercase)

print('Type Animal, Clothing, Weather, or Colors')

category=input()

if category not in categorytypes.keys():
  print('Your input isn\'t one of the catagories')
  print('Try entering again')
  print('Type Animal, Clothing, Weather, or Colors')
  category=int(input())

secretword = random.choice(categorytypes[category]).lower()

hiddenguessed = ('?'*len(secretword))

gamestate = 0

numberofguesses = 10

print(secretword)
print('')
print('The word you\'re after is ' + hiddenguessed)
print("\n you have {0} guesses".format(numberofguesses))
print('\nType one of the following letters:\n{0}'.format(", ".join(alphabet)))

while gamestate == 0:
  i = input()
  if i in secretword:
    alphabet.remove(i)
    print('You guessed correctly')
    hiddenguessed=[i if secretword[x]==i else hiddenguessed[x] for x in range(len(secretword))]
    hiddenguessed= ''.join(hiddenguessed)
    if hiddenguessed == secretword:
      gamestate = 2
      print("you win")
    else:
      print('Here is what you have so far {0}\nAvalable letters left:\n {1} \nGuess another letter\n'.format(hiddenguessed, ", ".join(alphabet)))

  else:
    alphabet.remove(i)
    print("You guessed wrong")
    print('You now have '+str(numberofguesses)+' guesses left.')
    if numberofguesses != 0:
      print('Here is what you have so far {0}\nAvalable letters left:\n {1} \nGuess another letter\n'.format(hiddenguessed, ", ".join(alphabet)))

  if numberofguesses == 0:
    gamestate = 1

  numberofguesses -= 1

if gamestate == 1:
  print("you lose lol\n")
```

Some cool stuff the other guy who posted doesn't use: .format, dictionaries, and the string library.

Comment: I figured the use of dictionaries would help a lot, but i'm not super comfortable with them yet and wanted to work on lists first.  As far as I can tell this works perfectly.  Another problem i'm running into a lot is that i don't know what a lot of the imports are capable of or what they even are.  I'll have to do some reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not contain all the bugs fixed - just a minimal amount to get it running.

```
import random                                                                                        

print('Welcome to hangman')                                                                          
print('Type one of the following catagories')                                                        

Animal=['Cat','Dog','Bird','Cow','Fish','Lizard']                                                    
Clothing=['Shirt','Jeans','Sweatshirt','Shoes','Hat','Scarf']                                        
Weather=['Rain','Snow','Sunny','Sleet','Windy','Stormy']                                             
Colors=['Red','Blue','Green','Purple','Yellow','Grey']                                               

Alphabet= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p',
           'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']                                                                                      

print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')                             

catagory=int(input())                                                                               
numberofguesses = 10                                                                                
while catagory > 4 or catagory < 0:                                                                                 
    print('Your input isn\'t one of the catagories. Make sure your choice is a number from 1 to 4.')
    print('Try entering again')                                                                     
    print('Type 1 for Animal, 2 for Clothing, 3 for Weather, 4 for Colors')                         
    catagory=int(input())                                                                           

if catagory == 1: secretword=random.choice(Animal)                           
if catagory == 2: secretword=random.choice(Clothing)                         
if catagory == 3: secretword=random.choice(Weather)                          
if catagory == 4: secretword=random.choice(Colors)                           

hiddenword = ['?' for x in secretword]
hiddenguessed = ''.join(hiddenword)

print('\nThe word you\'re after is ' + hiddenguessed + '\n')                                                                                                   
print('Type one of the following letters, it must be lowercase.')                  
print(Alphabet)                                                                    

i = input()                    

while numberofguesses > 0: 
    if i in secretword:
        if i in Alphabet:
            Alphabet.remove(i)
        print('\nYou guessed correctly')
        hiddenword=[i if i==y else x for x, y in zip(hiddenword, secretword)]
        hiddenguessed= ''.join(hiddenword)
        print('Here is what you have so far '+ hiddenguessed + '\n')
        print('Avalable letters left')
        print(Alphabet)      
        print('Guess another letter:')
        i=input()

    else:
        numberofguesses -= 1
        if i in Alphabet:
            Alphabet.remove(i)
        print("\nYou guessed wrong\n")
        print('Here is what you have so far '+ str(hiddenguessed) + '\n')
        print('You now have '+str(numberofguesses)+' guesses left.')
        print('Type one of the following letters, it must be lowercase.')
        print(Alphabet)
        i=input()
else:
    print('Congrats you have won the game.  ' + secretword + ' was the secret word')
```

Comment: `hiddenword=[i if i==y else x for x, y in zip(hiddenword, secretword)]` Would you be willing to break this section down and explain each piece.  Thanks, I ran it a couple times and it seems to work great.

Comment: `for x, y in zip(hiddenword, secretword)` allows iteration over *pairs* of letters from `hiddenword` and `secretword`. To see what this does, try playing with constructions such as `[(x, y) for x, y in zip(hiddenword, secretword)]`. Now the `i if i==y else x` part is setting the value of the new list to user input `i` if it is present in the secret word (=reveals the letter) and otherwise it leaves the letter unchanged.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have to play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

First, create a dictionary holding all the letters in the secretword with false as value (need to some kind of str.lower() though)

```
secretdict = {k:False for k in list(secretword)}
```

Then, if you get a hit you make that value true.
And in the loop you check if it is true.

```
if i in secretword:
    secretdict[i] = True
    hiddenword=[x if secretdict[x] == True else "?" for x in secretword]
```